# All custom taxonomy classes not showing despite hide_empty being false

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I've created a query which should list all of my terms from the custom taxonomy 'classes'. I know that by default it doesn't get terms which are empty, so I've added hide_empty' => false.

It still doesn't retrieve those terms which are empty. I realise I must have done something wrong here, and need to add in hide_empty' => false again somewhere

Any ideas?

```
<?php
$classes = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'classes',
    'hide_empty' => false

) );

if ( $classes ) {
    foreach ( $classes as $class ) {
        $terms = get_terms( $class );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if ( $term->parent != 0 ) {
                ?>

            <p><?php echo $term->name; ?></p>

                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why you called **$terms = get_terms( $class );** again after started the foreach, try to echo it without calling it again. Try the following:

```
<?php
$classes = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'classes',
    'hide_empty' => false

) );

if ( $classes ) {
    foreach ( $classes as $term) {
            if ( $term->parent != 0 ) {
                ?>

            <p><?php echo $term->name; ?></p>

                <?php
            }
     }

 }
?>
```

Also you can debug your code by dumping the returned variables, like the following, to understand where is the problem:

```
<?php
$classes = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'classes',
    'hide_empty' => false

) );

if ( $classes ) {
    foreach ( $classes as $class ) {
        $terms = get_terms( $class );
        var_dump($terms); //It's probably going to be 'false'
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            var_dump($term);
            if ( $term->parent != 0 ) {
                ?>

            <p><?php echo $term->name; ?></p>

                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```